# unload View after calling presentModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, sdk, view, switch-statement

I have some view controller which I call with the following method:

```
myViewController *myView = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    myView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
    [myView release];
```

if I use the app a few times I get a memory warning and the app freezes for a few seconds! I think the reason is that i switch the view but not discharged the old one !!?!!?!!
(i set my outlets to nil and release them)

how can I unload the old view after switching to the new one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When switching the view be sure to call dismissModalViewController:(BOOL)animated on myViewController.

Comment: thanks@ all for quick reply

I currently have my app so constructed that I can switch from each view   to each view - which is also provided for the implementation of the app. if i use dismissModalViewController i only can go for and back.

is there a possibility to rebuild it correct and easy so that I will discharge my memory but all the time can go to any view i want to?

Answer (score 0):

In the class that launch the modalViewController you could make a property for the modal viewcontroller which you retain. Then you could write something like this.

```
//This would be in an action or something...
if (self.myViewControllerProperty == nil) {
    self.myViewControllerProperty = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
}

[self presentModalViewController:self.myViewControllerProperty animated:YES];
```

Then instead of setting the

> myView.modalTransitionStyle =
>   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

Move that code to the modalViewController and write `self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;` I think that looks cleaner, keep the configuration of each viewcontroller separted don't mix it up.

And as the maclema said, call `dissmissModalViewController`, but you probably are doing that...

Answer (score 0):

Could be any number of problems but you don't need to (and can't) unload the old view. Make sure you are releasing objects and setting outlets to nil in `viewDidUnload` of all of your view controllers. `viewDidUnload` will be called when a memory warning occurs so if you don't handle it correctly you'll have leaks and can crash. Other than that, hard to know what else your app is doing that is contributing to the crash.